# Angular 4. Binding dynamic array elements

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-forms

In my ts file i have declared an array like

```
userData = [];
```

By an API i fill this array by whatever data i get.

```
this.userData = data['franchise'];
```

In my HTML file i am showing the data like this.

```
<div class="text-div">{{userData.fm_name != undefined ? userData.fm_name : ''}}</div>
```

All this is working fine in local but on production i am getting an error like

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
```

Please Help me here. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your userData looks like is a object, not an array, userData:any={};

Comment: if declaring it as object then i cannot run a loop on it.

Comment: but that worked. Thank You @Eliseo

Comment: Perhaps you are getting this error somewhere else. 'name' property you haven't used in above code.

Comment: @JayMomaya, I supouse you have an only user. If you definitely has an array of users, you must use  this.usersData.push(data['franchine']), the < *ngFor="let userData of this.usersData" >... (I change the name userData to usersData -with s-  because are many users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't got what you said but i think declaring your element like this

```
userData:any={};
```

should work.

And if you want to loop over an array then declare an array

```
loopArray = [];
this.loopArray = this.userdata['loopData'];
```